# How to save a text file in java after changing it?

Tags: java, file, text, save

in my project, I am opening text files, and im doing some changes to the files, and I want to save the file after im chaning it, like Save As with a location browse.
Can I do it somehow?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Little googling should help you.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to but I didnt find what I need..

Comment: How are you opening the files?  How are you changing them?

Comment: Im opening a file, and then I copy it into a string, then i change the string

Comment: In that case, you are *really* not searching properly.  Hint: saving a file is just writing a file.

Comment: Ofcurse, but how do I save it in a specific directory?

Comment: By specifying the directory in the path when you open the file.  Seriously dude, read the javadocs, read the Oracle Java Tutorial.  This is all very, very basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that should help you:
[Binary streams](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245)

Or you can maybe try this: [Reading/writing text files](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=1E5FDDB607C1CFF8999C059B46BB7B84?Id=42)

Answer (score 0):

A little search over the internet will help. Here;s a basic program that will read from one file and write to other. You can modify as per your requirement.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyFile {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {
      FileInputStream in = null;
      FileOutputStream out = null;

      try {
         in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
         out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");

         int c;
         while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
         }
      }finally {
         if (in != null) {
            in.close();
         }
         if (out != null) {
            out.close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Some more tutorials here:

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaIO/article.html
- http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-io-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

You should offer some code. However, yes by Using e.g. [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) you just open your File with `FileWriter(File file, boolean append=true)` and call close() when your done. Saving is automatic so to say.